# Can't extend SpannableStringBuilder?

Tags: android, class, spannablestring

I need to create a custom class by extending SpannableStringBuilder.

I havent even added anything to the class yet. So my class goes like this.

```
public class xyz extends SpannableStringBuilder{

}
```

But when I try to use this class instead of SpannableStringBuilder app crashes.
It is working fine when I use SpannableStringBuilder.

I have tried adding the constructors too.

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 1):

When you call xyz(), are you passing in any parameters? If so, make sure you call the appropriate super() constructor from your xyz constructor.

Comment: Im not calling a constructor, im just casting.
`myvariable =(xyz)(textView.getText());` not working
myvariable =(SpannableStringBuilder)(textView.getText()); working.

Comment: `xyz spannable =(xyz)(textView.getText());`

Comment: When I replace xyz with SpannableStringBuilder in the above line it works fine  @Justin

Comment: Have you tried `xyz spannable = new xyz(textView.getText());`?

Comment: Yes it doesnt work. I mean the `textView` here is a EdidText. So it brings errors when editing the text later. (wrks for this statement only)

Comment: What does your error say when the cast doesn't work?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableStringBuilder cannot be cast to com.esfsd.fsdfsd.qwerty.MainActivity$xyz

Comment: I think it's failing because xyz is an inner class of MainActivity. I would separate it out into its own java file and make it its own class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91864/discussion-between-sadeepdarshana-and-justin-powell).

Comment: not working yet, thanks for ur time. 
btw i'm doing this all to extent SpannableStringBuilder so that i can make a Serializable SpannableStringBuilder and store data in a file. Converting between html is not sufficiant for me. (Im creating a rich text editor and want to save the doc). Any alternatives for this? @Justin